# Gitlab CI: Access private repository from CI pipeline fails

Tags: symfony, gitlab, continuous-integration, composer-php, gitlab-ci

I try to set up a Gitlab CI configuration, which executes the unit tests of a symfony project. The same configuration works for an old project, but in my new one the command `composer update` fails. The error message says that it isn’t possible to clone our own bundle out of our Gitlab.

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
In Git.php line 471:

 Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- ‘https://glp...XXX:private-token@gi
 tlab.company.com/bundle/test-bundle.git’ ‘/tmp/cache/vcs/https---gitla
 b.company.com-bundle-test-bundle.git/’

 Cloning into bare repository ‘/tmp/cache/vcs/https---gitlab.company.com-bundle-test-bundle.git’...
 fatal: unable to access ‘https://gitlab.company.com/bundle/test-bundle
 .git/’: Failed to connect to gitlab.company.com port 443 after 0 ms: Conn
 ection refused
```

At first I tried to use a personal access token in my `.gitlab-ci.yaml` but get the previous mentioned error.

```
test:
  image: composer:latest
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - composer config gitlab-token.gitlab.company.com $PERSONAL_CI_TOKEN
```

After that I tried the access by username/password.

```
echo "{\"http-basic\":{\"gitlab.company.com\":{\"username\":\"user\",\"password\":\"password\"}}}” > $HOME/.composer/auth.json
```

All the possibilities worked in my composer docker container and in my other project the access is still possible. I don't know how to solve this error.

Comment: This error clearly states that gitlab.company.com:443 is not accessible from within your ci container. Can you confirm it? Debug dns resolution (how gitlab.company.com is resolved?), try `curl  -v 'https://gitlab.company.com'` as a pipeline step, what error will it return? Check if you have some sort of reverse proxy on top of your gitlab instance, which is not accessible from runners. Maybe you have some kind of internal gitlab address, like gitlab.internal.company.com, which works from within your network boundary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if you have added your self-hosted gitlab domain in your config in the composer.json file.

It should look like this:

```
"config": { "gitlab-domains": ["gitlab.company.com"] }
```